# Error in in linking makefile (exit code 1)

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu-18.04, makefile

This is my first time using makefile. I am getting "linker command failed with exit code 1 " error while using "clang".

I just linked .h files in makefile and run make all in ubuntu teminal.

```
CC_EXEC = clang
CC_FLAGS = -g

CC = ${CC_EXEC} ${CC_FLAGS}

BUILD_DIR = build

all: executable.out

executable.out:  ${BUILD_DIR}/main.o  ${BUILD_DIR}/UTrelloInterface.o  ${BUILD_DIR}/User.o  ${BUILD_DIR}/List.o  ${BUILD_DIR}/Task.o
    clang -g ${BUILD_DIR}/main.o ${BUILD_DIR}/UTrelloInterface.o ${BUILD_DIR}/User.o ${BUILD_DIR}/List.o ${BUILD_DIR}/Task.o -o ${BUILD_DIR}/executable.out


${BUILD_DIR}/main.o: main.cpp UTrelloInterface.h User.h List.h Task.h
    ${CC} -c main.cpp -o ${BUILD_DIR}/main.o

${BUILD_DIR}/User.o: User.cpp User.h
    ${CC} -c User.cpp -o ${BUILD_DIR}/User.o

${BUILD_DIR}/List.o: List.cpp List.h
    ${CC} -c List.cpp -o ${BUILD_DIR}/List.o

${BUILD_DIR}/Task.o: Task.cpp Task.h
    ${CC} -c Task.cpp -o ${BUILD_DIR}/Task.o
${BUILD_DIR}/UTrelloInterface.o: UTrelloInterface.cpp UTrelloInterface.h Task.h List.h User.h
    ${CC} -c UTrelloInterface.cpp -o ${BUILD_DIR}/UTrelloInterface.o

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf build/ && mkdir -p build
```

I got exactly this error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
makefile:11: recipe for target 'executable.out' failed
make: *** [executable.out] Error 1
```

I got this error while using g++ compiler:

```
g++ -g -c User.cpp -o build/User.o
g++ -g build/main.o build/UTrelloInterface.o build/User.o build/List.o build/Task.o -o build/executable.out
/usr/bin/ld: build/main.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:11: recipe for target 'executable.out' failed
make: *** [executable.out] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: there will be more details in the compile output somewhere

Comment: I added error I got while using g++.

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear: you need to add `-fPIC` to your compiler flags.

Comment: what command should i type exactly to compile with this -fPIC?

Comment: I'm not an expert with clang, but I think the command would be e.g. `${CC} -fPIC -c main.cpp -o ${BUILD_DIR}/main.o`. Equivalently, you could add a line: `CC_FLAGS += -fPIC`. (Note that once you get this makefile working, you can simplify it quite a lot.)

Comment: I just changed the file and problem solved, I don not know what the problem exactly was!!!